# Import file with string python for certain condition

Tags: python, file, scrapy

I am trying to import a txt file to a list in python.
What am I doing right now

```
with open('my_connection_page.txt', 'r') as f:
    url = f.readlines()
```

It just put everything into the `url[0]`.

This is the Text file

[u'/scheck/', u'/amanda/', u'/in/amanda/', u'/462aa6aa/', u'/462aa6aa/', u'/895161106/', u'/895161106/', u'/anshabenhudson/']

What should I do?

Comment: Why does your text file contain Python code?  If your text file contained lines of text, it would work.

Comment: It is a text file. The answer below works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `url = f.read().split()` instead. You can use delimiter in `split()`.